# .htaccess RewriteRule for specific query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I would like to RewriteRule for a Specific query attribute

e.g.

```
https://website.com/shop/?req=cosmetics
```

to:

```
https://website.com/shop/cosmetics
```

I achieved that by doing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^shop/(.+)$ shop/?req=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My problem is that this will replace any query attribute...

What i'm looking for is to perform the RewriteRule explicit on '?req=' and let any other attr e.g. '?foo=' just to pass and execute.

I know that this is possible with RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} but i can't make it work...

Thanks

Comment: Your rule is rewriting `/shop/<anything>` to `/shop/?req=<anything>`. What change do you want in this rewrite behavior?

Comment: I would like to ignore the rewriting rule in any other case but '?req='. So if i send /shop/?foo=whatever it should just ignore it like i never had any rewriting rule.

Comment: so i assume that i need a condition something like this %{QUERY_STRING} ^?req= . Only then it should let the rewrite rule to happen!

Comment: Is this your complete .htaccess? As I said you current rule is is rewriting `/shop/<anything>` to `/shop/?req=<anything>`. If you enter in browser `/shop/?foo=<anything>` then current rule isn't doing anything.

Comment: Hey anubhava, it turns out that i had a bug going on in my code... I was not returning false after my ?foo=test request, the code was just keep going doing other staff so i got confused... Thanks for confirming that this peace of code is correct!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change first rule and do something like this,otherwise server can't predict itself other query string except the existing one `req`   :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)/(.*)$ /shop/?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

So, the Request `https://website.com/shop/?req=cosmetics` will be from `https://website.com/shop/req/cosmetics` request and .as you suggested , `https://website.com/shop/?foo=cosmetics` will be from `https://website.com/shop/foo/cosmetics` request

If you want to apply this code from shop directory `.htaccess` file :

```
   RewriteEngine On       
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/merchant 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

it will exclude `merchant` as well , Test it .

Comment: My app lives in the same directory '/shop/' the process is happening internally by checking the query attributes '/shop/?req=cosmetics' is to fetch cosmetic products, but i would like when i have e.g. /shop/?merchant=123 to NOT do any rewriterute! So i want the RewriteRule to happen ONLY when i have /shop/?req=<something>

Comment: Hey Mohammed Elhag, thanks for checking in to this, it turns out that i had a bug in my code that got me confused! :/